# sscanf() causing infinite loop by changing the index value of for loop

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Function:

```c
void input_bytes(unsigned char bytes[], int num_bytes)
{
    const int CHAR_PER_BYTE = 2; /* expects hex input */
    const int STRING_SIZE = num_bytes * CHAR_PER_BYTE;

    char input_string[STRING_SIZE + 1];  /* + 1 for null char */
    int ind;
    unsigned char byte;

    fgets(input_string, STRING_SIZE + 1, stdin);

    printf("after fgets\n");

    for (ind = 0; ind < num_bytes; ind++)
    {
        printf("top of loop, ind: %d\n", ind);

        sscanf(input_string, "%2x", &byte);
        bytes[ind] = byte;

        printf("bottom of loop, ind: %d\n", ind);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Driver:

```c
int main()
{
    unsigned char bytes[5];

    input_bytes(bytes, 5);
}
```

Output:

```
after fgets
top of loop, ind: 0
bottom of loop, ind: 0
top of loop, ind: 1
bottom of loop, ind: 0
top of loop, ind: 1
bottom of loop, ind: 0
top of loop, ind: 1
bottom of loop, ind: 0
top of loop, ind: 1
bottom of loop, ind: 0
top of loop, ind: 1
bottom of loop, ind: 0
top of loop, ind: 1
bottom of loop, ind: 0
top of loop, ind: 1
bottom of loop, ind: 0
top of loop, ind: 1
bottom of loop, ind: 0
...
```

Compiling with `gcc driver.c -o driver`.

I put an `ind++` in the loop out of curiosity and it goes to 2 at the top and 1 at the bottom. If I take the `sscanf()` out it terminates.

Comment: You shouldn't add 1 for the null byte, because `fgets()` already accounts for that.

Comment: My array doesn't account for that.

Comment: The point is that telling it `STRING_SIZE+1` means that it can write the null byte outside the array.

Comment: The argument should be the size of the buffer. It will read at most `size-1` bytes so that there's room for the null byte.

Comment: The variable for `%2x` format must be `int`, not `char`.

Comment: You're scanning the first 2 characters of `input_string` every time through the loop.

Comment: Barmar, yes it should be equivalent to string size, the confusion there was I did not have the + 1 when declaring the sting.

Comment: Barmar, the first 2 of input comment is true, but it doesn't change the issue.

Comment: Okay it was the fact that `%2x` expected an int. I tested beforehand tho and saw no issues outside of a loop. What is the reasoning for that? Oh, is it that it's writing outside the bounds of the char?

Comment: Because it's writing outside the variable, which causes undefined behavior, such as changing the value of the `ind` variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214934/discussion-between-young-souvlaki-and-barmar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable corresponding to `%x` format must be `int`, not `char`. Using the wrong type results in undefined behavior; in your program, it's writing `0` to `ind`, so the loop never stops.

The `size` argument to `fgets()` should be the size of the buffer, without adding 1. `fgets()` will subtract 1 to get the number of characters it can read before the null. You should add 1 to the size of `input_string`, not the argument to `fgets()`.

`fgets()` also includes the newline in the input that it returns, you need to add room for that to `input_string` as well.

If you want to convert all the bytes in the input, you need to scan from a different index in `input_string` each time through the loop.

```
void input_bytes(unsigned char bytes[], int num_bytes)
{
    const int CHAR_PER_BYTE = 2; /* expects hex input */
    const int STRING_SIZE = num_bytes * CHAR_PER_BYTE + 2; // + 2 for newline and null byte

    char input_string[STRING_SIZE];
    int ind;
    unsigned int byte;

    fgets(input_string, STRING_SIZE, stdin); /* + 1 for null char */

    printf("after fgets\n");

    for (ind = 0; ind < num_bytes; ind++)
    {
        printf("top of loop, ind: %d\n", ind);

        sscanf(&input_string[2*ind], "%2x", &byte);
        bytes[ind] = byte;

        printf("bottom of loop, ind: %d\n", ind);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Since you're not actually performing any string operations on `input_string`. You could make it exactly `num_bytes * CHAR_PER_BYTE` characters long, without adding space for the newline and null. Instead of using `fgets()`, use `fread()` to read exactly the number of characters you want:

```
fread(input_string, CHAR_PER_BYTE, num_bytes, stdin);
```

Comment: After some testing it appears `fread()` leaves the newline for the next input call. Also, shouldn't `size` be `1`? `2` exceeds the size of `char`.

Comment: Yes, `fread()` leaves the newline. You need to skip over it some other way.

Comment: `size` is `2` because we want to read 2 characters for every byte. I've replaced it with `CHAR_PER_BYTE`, does that make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, but then input string is a char array and you can't store 2 bytes in one char type.

Comment: You've got it backwards. `input_string` contains 2 characters for every 1 byte.

Comment: So C doesn't try to put the given size `2` in one index, it knows to split it among 2 indices because of the data type?

Comment: `fread()` simply reads `size * nelements` bytes into the memory beginning at `ptr`. The distinction between `size` and `nelements` is irrelevant to it.